# Using the library generic classes without using its generic feature will make it raw type?

Tags: java, generics

I am learning java, and I have got around to the topic of Generics and raw types. I have found that I had been using some library classes in Java which are generic (didn't know it before), and I had been using them as if they are just normal classes (declaring them like a normal object). Will that lead to the raw types? And since raw types are said to be avoided, should I, before using any of the library classes or interfaces of Java, make sure whether they are generic or not? And if a class is generic then use it as it meant to (parameterized type)?

Comment: If you're working on Java 5+, the compiler will throw a warning when an interface/class can use generics. You should use the generics every time you need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a class is declared like this:

```
public class MyClass<T>
```

And you use it like this:

```
MyClass myVariable = new MyClass();
```

Then yes, it indeed is a raw type, and you shouldn't use it.
Collection classes (like `ArrayList`)
are generic on Java 5+, and you should always use the generic variant
when it's available. Watch the compiler warnings;
they notify about using generics, among other things.

Comment: The compiler will throw a warning here. You should use the class T type like integer for example:   `MyClass<Integer> myVariable = new MyClass<Integer>();`

Answer (score 0):

Look at this sample class:

```
class Queue<T> {
   private LinkedList<T> items = new LinkedList<T>();
   public void enqueue(T item) {
      items.addLast(item);
   }
   public T dequeue() {
      return items.removeFirst();
   }
   public boolean isEmpty() {
      return (items.size() == 0);
   }
}
```

Which is a generic class with type T. you can build an instance of he class with any type needed to associate with the type needed to use internally.

you can instantiate the class as follows if you want to  use Integer type for example:

```
Queue<Integer> queue = new Queue<Integer>();
```

You can also use more than one type in a class as follows:

```
class Pair<T,S> {
   public T first;
   public S second;
   public Pair( T a, S b ) {
      first = a;
      second = b;
   }
}
```

And instantiate it like this:

```
Pair<String,Color> colorName = new Pair<String,Color>("Red", Color.RED);
```

Or like this:

```
Pair<Double,Double> coordinates = new Pair<Double,Double>(17.3,42.8);
```